# Find the $A_3$-invariant field of $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Let $K$ be the splitting field of $P(X)=X^3 - 3X^2 + 3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Determine
>   $G = \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$. For every subgroup $H < G$, find $K^H$.

By Eisenstein's Criterion, $P(X)=X^3-3X^2+3$ is irreducible. $D(P)=-4\times (-81)\times 3-27\times 9=3^5$. Since $\text{Char}(\mathbb{Q})=0$, the Galois group $G$ is $\Sigma_3$. Therefore, $H$ is $\{e\}$ or $\{e, (12)\}$ or $\{e, (13)\}$ or $\{e, (23)\}$ or $A_3$ or $\Sigma_3$.

I can not find the radical solution of this equation so I can't proceed anymore. Any hints are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: $\Sigma_3$ has more subgroups than that, though. They aren't normal, but they are still subgroups.

Comment: Yes, $\{e\}, \Sigma_2, A_3, \Sigma_3$. I've edited, thanks.

Comment: It has three different copies of $\Sigma_2$, though. Each corresponds to a different subfield.

Comment: oo, but how to solve this equation...

Comment: The same theorem you used in deciding whether the Galois group is $S_3$ or $A_3$ also describes a non-trivial element of $K^{A_3}$.

Comment: to me it seems that the discriminant of $P$ is $81$.

Comment: You are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's determine the Galois group of $P(X) = X^3 - 3X^2 + 3$.

The discriminant of the general trinomial $X^3 + aX^2 + b$ is $\Delta = -b(4a^3 + 27b)$. In our case we have $\Delta = 81$ which is a square. This tells us that the Galois group is $A_3$.

The only subgroup of that is the trivial group, so there are no nontrivial subfields. The $A_3$ invariant subfield would just be $\mathbb Q$.